# Use remove_meta_box conditionally on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, metabox, hooks, actions

I have a custom post type of people with some custom taxonomy boxes, i want to hide these when on child pages. I have found remove_meta_box works fine but i just can't access the $post object within the action.

Currently i have

```
function remove_post_custom_fields($post) {
  global $post;
  if( count($post->ancestors) > 0 ){
    remove_meta_box( 'staff-typediv' , 'people' , 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'practice-areadiv' , 'people' , 'normal' ); 
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_custom_fields' );
```

I have tried `count($post->ancestors) > 0` and also just `$post->post_parent` but neither work.

Anyone any clue how to access $post variables within this action?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a small custom function to check the current post (page or other post type) if is parent exist, like the follow function.

```
/**
 * if the post is a subpage for ID.
 *
 * $post object The post.
 * 
 * return boolean
 */
function is_child( $post ) {

    // If is sub_post
    if ( is_page() && ( $post->post_parent === $post->ID ) ) 
               return TRUE;
    else 
               return FALSE;
};
```

I think it is sufficient to check the type and the `post_parent` param, but with the ID is it clean and solid. For your requirements should you switch the `is_page()` conditional function to `( 'people' === get_post_type() )`.

The helper function `is_child` can you now use in your test before you remove the meta boxes, like this.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_post_custom_fields' );
function remove_post_custom_fields( $post ) {

  if ( is_child( $post ) ){
    remove_meta_box( 'staff-typediv' , 'people' , 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'practice-areadiv' , 'people' , 'normal' ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to get rid of the global stuff  ;-)

Comment: You have right, was not in my focus on this question, but it is a point for clean coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `do_meta_boxes` hook:

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', function( $post_type, $context, $post )
{
    // Nothing to do if context isn't 'normal'
    if( 'normal' !== $context )
        return;

    // Nothing to do if post type isn't 'people'
    if( 'people' !== $post_type )
        return;

    // Nothing to do with no post parents
    if( $post instanceof \WP_Post && 0 == $post->post_parent )
        return;

    // Remove meta boxes
    foreach( [ 'staff-typediv', 'practice-areadiv' ] as $id )   
        remove_meta_box( $id, $post_type, $context );

}, 10, 3 );
```

Here we target the *normal* context, but hopefully you can adjust it to your needs.